# Error -2147467259(80004005) : GROUP BY is giving error while executing SQL-query thru Excel-VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc

I am using OLE Automation Library for using SQL thru Excel-VBA.
[image]

But while using the `GROUP BY` SQL function, I am getting Runtime error.
[image]

following SQL query is WORKING

```
strSQL = "SELECT [PO_No] FROM [SAP_Dump$]"
```

following SQL queries are NOT working

```
strSQL = "SELECT [PO_No] MAX([Amendment_No]) FROM [SAP_Dump$] GROUP BY [SAP_Dump$].[PO_No]"

strSQL = "SELECT [PO_No] FROM [SAP_Dump$] GROUP BY [SAP_Dump$].[PO_No]"
```

Comment: No aggregate functions? Do SELECT DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY.

Comment: Hmmm...the second SQL is valid.  Try using this: `SELECT [PO_No] FROM [SAP_Dump$] GROUP BY [PO_No]` ... or maybe this: `SELECT DISTINCT [PO_No] FROM [SAP_Dump$]`

Comment: `DISTINCT` will not solve the purpose, because I have to apply `SUM()` or `MAX()` etc functions for further task...

Comment: strSQL = "SELECT [PO_No] FROM [SAP_Dump$] GROUP BY [PO_No]"

Comment: @Dmitrij Holkin! also tried this one, but not working...

Comment: Show full code with data connection

Comment: ```VBA
Public Sub getData(strSQL As String)
    
    If Not (CBool(cnn.State)) Then: cnn.Open
    Debug.Print strSQL
    rssql.Open strSQL, cnn

    Sheets("Summary").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rssql    'Pasting result records at B1 of Activesheet
    
End Sub

Private Sub Connection_setup(fPath As String)

    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & fPath & ";"
    
    Set rssql = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rssql.CursorLocation = 3

End Sub
```

Comment: `strSQL = "SELECT [PO_No] FROM [SAP_Dump$]"` is working fine

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this `GROUP BY`?

Comment: You should either use `DISTINCT` instead, or add your aggregate functions (`SUM()`, `MAX()` or whatever else you need) into the query.

Comment: @NellieDanielyan : I want to do `Max()` operation... refer question (edited just now)...